# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$ and integral test

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

I have read online, that one can show that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n = -\frac{1}{12}$.

But isn't this a Riemann Series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$, where $p=-1$.

And if so, can't you prove that

$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \int^N \frac{1}{x^{-1}} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{2} = \infty$,

thus, by the integral test for convergence, the series diverges? Where is my mistake?

Comment: ...if this is a serious question, you must look into analytic continuation. Either that, or string theory. You cannot use calc 2 to prove it. There is a tricky way to prove with sums which can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Comment: @IanMateus My question isn't why $1+2+3+... = -\frac{1}{12}$, but why the integral test gives a 'WRONG' result in this case. I am realy not interested in a prove, but why the prove that it the statement is wrong itself seems to be 'wrong'.

Comment: Short answer: you are right, this **does not converge** and the value $-1/12$ is instead associated to $\zeta(-1)$, a "extended version" of $p$-series. This abuse of notation was exhaustively addressed on his site before. As dylan7 noted, the integral test cannot be applied to this test blindly (as this series is not monotone decreasing) but you can easily show by area comparison that the sum is divergent.

Comment: You are correct that the series diverges, as Ian points out, and the Divergence Test is the easiest way to show this.

Comment: @IanMateus So you can prove clearly that the series is divergent, but it still converges to $-\frac{1}{12}$?

Comment: To make the situation clearer, you probably know $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}.$$ This means $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k=1+2+4+8+\cdots = \frac{1}{1-2}=-1,$$ right? Err, no. This does not converge to $-1$, we are outside the area of convergence $|x|<1$. But I can abuse the notation and write $1+2+4+\cdots=-1$ if I want, even though this is *outside the area of convergence*. This is very, very, similar to what is happening: the $-1$ is outside the area of convergence of the sum. I suggest you take a look at the many questions previously asked and try to digest the information.

Answer (score 0):

I think a requirement of the integral test is that $ f (n) $ be monotone decreasing.

Check
http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/tests.htm.
Under integral test.